# Accessing Redbean many-to-many entries without many queries?

Tags: php, sql, redbean

I've got two tables, `table1` and `table2`, connected via many-to-many.
So far there is no problem, but I would get a server-collapse for using the code below in productive usage. 
Accessing the many-to-many-join generates far to much queries.

Is there some better way to access the data (without raw querys)?

### Code:

```
<?php
$table1_entry = R::findAll('table1');
foreach($table1_entry as $table1)
{
    echo $table1->id;
    foreach($table1->sharedTable2 as $table2)
    {
        echo $table2->id;
    }
}
?>
```

### Redbean Query-Log:

```
string(34) "SELECT * FROM `table1` -- keep-cache"
  [1] =>
  string(71) "SELECT * FROM `table2_table1` WHERE ( `table1_id`  IN ( ?)  )  -- keep-cache"
  [2] =>
  string(61) "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE ( `id`  IN ( 1)  )  -- keep-cache"
  [3] =>
  string(71) "SELECT * FROM `table2_table1` WHERE ( `table1_id`  IN ( ?)  )  -- keep-cache"
  [4] =>
  string(61) "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE ( `id`  IN ( 2)  )  -- keep-cache"
  [5] =>
  string(71) "SELECT * FROM `table2_table1` WHERE ( `table1_id`  IN ( ?)  )  -- keep-cache"
  [6] =>
  string(61) "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE ( `id`  IN ( 3)  )  -- keep-cache"
  [7] =>
  string(71) "SELECT * FROM `table2_table1` WHERE ( `table1_id`  IN ( ?)  )  -- keep-cache"
  [8] =>
  string(61) "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE ( `id`  IN ( 4)  )  -- keep-cache"
  [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
//Create some pages and ads
list($ad1, $ad2) = R::dispense('ad', 2);
list($page1, $page2, $page3) = R::dispense('page',3);
$ad1->sharedPage = array($page1, $page2);
$ad2->sharedPage[] = $page3;
R::storeAll(array($ad1, $ad2));

//to check
R::debug(1);

//Now given the ads 
R::each(R::find('ad'), 'sharedPage|page',function($ad, $pages){
  foreach($pages as $page) echo "\n AD {$ad->id} -> PAGE {$page->id} ";
});
```

Note that in RedBeanPHP you have to use

```
'sharedPage'=>'page'
```

instead of

```
'sharedPage|page'):
```

More details can be found here:

http://www.redbeanphp.com/eager_loading

Comment: Not much better.... `array(4) { [0] => "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE word like "A%" [1] => "SELECT * FROM table2_table1 WHERE ( table1_id  IN ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,[...])" [2] => "SELECT * FROM table2_table1 WHERE ( id  IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,[...]" [3] => "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ( id  IN ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,[...]"`